# How can developers access to Nexus OSS

Tags: jenkins, nexus

Can someone tell me how exactly developers can acces to Nexus OSS ? Have i to install it in one server apart with Jenkins for exemple in a VM and after that what i have to do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus Repository Manager is a separate application from Jenkins. You can run it in the same or a different VM. After installation you just have to configure the tools you use to connect to it for downloads and publishing and potentially configure repositories.

In terms of the tools e.g. we have a [full chapter about configuring Apache Maven and others to Maven repositories](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config.html) as well as example projects. And similar for other formats.

All that and a lot more is covered in the [documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/).

Comment: Thnx for the reply @Manfred : I know Jenkins is a separate application but i will face both of them soon and i choose Nexus OSS because he's the "MVP" in repository manager . You said : " You have to configure the Tools" that's what i mean : like TeamViewer or Remote Desktop Connection for Windows ?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thnx for the edit @Manfred : But still didn't found the answer maybe i didn't really understand the documents or you didn't understand my question : If i put Nexus OSS in the computer A : if some persons of the team of developers working in the computer B want to access  to A : how can he access to the computer A ? What type of acces and what tools will use it ? Thnx

Comment: Its a web application and you can just access the user interface via HTTP/S. And beyond that it depends on the tool. But its mostly HTTP based as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Manfred Moser . Please i searched a long in sonatype site for documents about migrating from Archiva to Nexus Mileston 6 or 7 ( Nexus OSS 3.0) but i didn't find anything. It's normal ?

Comment: Yes... currently migration to 3.x will be released with the 3.1 release.